# C# subarray of strings with LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq, startswith, sub-array

I have an array of strings and I have to take only those entries, which
are starting with "81" or "82". I've tried it like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName); // This returns an array of strings
lines = lines.TakeWhile(item => item.StartsWith("81") ||item.StartsWith("82")).ToArray();
```

but this just doesn't work. It retuns an empty string array.

When I loop through lines with a for-loop and compare everytime

```
if (!firstline.Substring(0, 2).StartsWith("81")) continue;
```

and then I take the required entries, it's working just fine.

Any suggestions how to get it right with LINQ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `Where()`:

```
lines = lines.Where(item => item.StartsWith("81") || item.StartsWith("82")).ToArray();
```

`TakeWhile` will take sequence until condition becomes false, but `Where`  will continue and find all elements matching the condition.